# datetime timestamp using Python with microsecond level accuracy

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I am trying to get timestamps that are accurate down to the microsecond on Windows OS and macOS in Python 3.10+.

On Windows OS, I have noticed Python's built-in `time.time()` (paired with `datetime.fromtimestamp()`) and `datetime.datetime.now()` seem to have a slower clock.  They don't have enough resolution to differentiate microsecond-level events.  The good news is `time` functions like `time.perf_counter()` and `time.time_ns()` *do* seem to use a clock that is fast enough to measure microsecond-level events.

Sadly, I can't figure out how to get them into `datetime` objects.  How can I get the output of `time.perf_counter()` or [PEP 564](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/)'s nanosecond resolution time functions into a `datetime` object?

Note: I don't need nanosecond-level stuff, so it's okay to throw away out precision below 1-μs).

---

**Current Solution**

This is my current (hacky) solution, which actually works fine, but I am wondering if there's a cleaner way:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Final

IMPORT_TIMESTAMP: Final[datetime] = datetime.now()
INITIAL_PERF_COUNTER: Final[float] = time.perf_counter()


def get_timestamp() -> datetime:
    """Get a high resolution timestamp with μs-level precision."""
    dt_sec = time.perf_counter() - INITIAL_PERF_COUNTER
    return IMPORT_TIMESTAMP + timedelta(seconds=dt_sec)
```

Comment: It's impossible to use the output of `time.perf_counter` to get an absolute time. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter): "The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid."

Comment: @DeepSpace please see the updated question.  It's possible to adapt to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's almost as good as it gets, since *the C module, if available, overrides all classes defined in the pure Python implementation of the `datetime` module with the fast C implementation*, and there are no hooks.
Reference: [python/cpython@cf86e36](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/cf86e368ebd17e10f68306ebad314eea31daaa1e#diff-f920da77b137d2e8eedf287c987745a3ff99c83d20a6332f656b35d12c479d10)

Note that:

1. There's an intrinsic sub-microsecond error in the accuracy equal to the time it takes between obtaining the system time in `datetime.now()` and obtaining the performance counter time.
2. There's a sub-microsecond performance cost to add a `datetime` and a `timedelta`.

Depending on your specific use case if calling multiple times, that may or may not matter.

A slight improvement would be:

```py
INITIAL_TIMESTAMP: Final[float] = time.time()
INITIAL_TIMESTAMP_PERF_COUNTER: Final[float] = time.perf_counter()

def get_timestamp_float() -> float:
    dt_sec = time.perf_counter() - INITIAL_TIMESTAMP_PERF_COUNTER
    return INITIAL_TIMESTAMP + dt_sec

def get_timestamp_now() -> datetime:
    dt_sec = time.perf_counter() - INITIAL_TIMESTAMP_PERF_COUNTER
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(INITIAL_TIMESTAMP + dt_sec)
```

---

## Anecdotal numbers

Windows:

```py
# Intrinsic error
timeit.timeit('datetime.now()', setup='from datetime import datetime')/1000000  # 0.31 μs
timeit.timeit('time.time()', setup='import time')/1000000                       # 0.07 μs

# Performance cost
setup = 'from datetime import datetime, timedelta; import time'
timeit.timeit('datetime.now() + timedelta(1.000001)', setup=setup)/1000000            # 0.79 μs
timeit.timeit('datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time() + 1.000001)', setup=setup)/1000000  # 0.44 μs
```

```sh
# Resolution
min get_timestamp_float() delta: 239 ns
```

Windows and macOS:

|  | Windows | macOS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| # Intrinsic error |  |  |
| `timeit.timeit('datetime.now()', setup='from datetime import datetime')/1000000` | 0.31 μs | 0.61 μs |
| `timeit.timeit('time.time()', setup='import time')/1000000` | 0.07 μs | 0.08 μs |
| # Performance cost |  |  |
| `setup = 'from datetime import datetime, timedelta; import time'` | - | - |
| `timeit.timeit('datetime.now() + timedelta(1.000001)', setup=setup)/1000000` | 0.79 μs | 1.26 μs |
| `timeit.timeit('datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time() + 1.000001)', setup=setup)/1000000` | 0.44 μs | 0.69 μs |
| # Resolution |  |  |
| `min time() delta` (benchmark) | *x* ms | 716 ns |
| `min get_timestamp_float() delta` | 239 ns | 239 ns |

239 ns is the smallest difference that `float` allows at the magnitude of Unix time, as noted by [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) in the comments.

```py
x = time.time()
print((math.nextafter(x, 2*x) - x) * 1e9)  # 238.4185791015625
```

### Script

Resolution script, based on https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#script:

```py
import math
import time
from typing import Final

LOOPS = 10 ** 6

INITIAL_TIMESTAMP: Final[float] = time.time()
INITIAL_TIMESTAMP_PERF_COUNTER: Final[float] = time.perf_counter()

def get_timestamp_float() -> float:
    dt_sec = time.perf_counter() - INITIAL_TIMESTAMP_PERF_COUNTER
    return INITIAL_TIMESTAMP + dt_sec

min_dt = [abs(time.time() - time.time())
          for _ in range(LOOPS)]
min_dt = min(filter(bool, min_dt))
print("min time() delta: %s ns" % math.ceil(min_dt * 1e9))

min_dt = [abs(get_timestamp_float() - get_timestamp_float())
          for _ in range(LOOPS)]
min_dt = min(filter(bool, min_dt))
print("min get_timestamp_float() delta: %s ns" % math.ceil(min_dt * 1e9))
```

Comment: Your first sentence in the answer "That's almost as good as it gets" is all I needed. Saved me time. Thanks.